# Blazor: SendGrid not sending emails to confirm account

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, sendgrid

Been trying to get email sending to work in Blazor to allow users to confirm emails and reset passwords. I have followed the documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/accconfirm?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio and looked over it over and over but I can't seem to figure out why the email does not send.

API Key has been set to Full Access

### Startup.cs

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(
                Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

        services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();

        services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
            .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

        services.AddIdentityServer()
            .AddApiAuthorization<ApplicationUser, ApplicationDbContext>(options => {
                options.IdentityResources["openid"].UserClaims.Add("role");
                options.ApiResources.Single().UserClaims.Add("role");
            });
        // Need to do this as it maps "role" to ClaimTypes.Role and causes issues
        JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Remove("role");

        services.AddAuthentication()
            .AddIdentityServerJwt();

        services.AddControllersWithViews();

        services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, EmailSender>();
        services.Configure<AuthMessageSenderOptions>(Configuration);


        services.AddRazorPages();

        services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
        options.ClaimsIdentity.UserIdClaimType = ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);

       services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson(x => x.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Serialize);

}

public class AuthMessageSenderOptions
{
    public string SendGridKey { get; set; }
}
```

### Email sender

```
public class EmailSender : IEmailSender
{
    public EmailSender(IOptions<AuthMessageSenderOptions> optionsAccessor)
    {
        Options = optionsAccessor.Value;
    }

    public AuthMessageSenderOptions Options { get; }

    public Task SendEmailAsync(string email, string subject, string message)
    {
        return Execute(Options.SendGridKey, subject, message, email);
    }

    public Task Execute(string apiKey, string subject, string message, string email)
    {
        var client = new SendGridClient(apiKey);
        var msg = new SendGridMessage()
        {
            From = new EmailAddress("info@example.com", "Identity Demo"),
            Subject = subject,
            PlainTextContent = message,
            HtmlContent = message
        };
        msg.AddTo(new EmailAddress(email));

        // Disable click tracking.
        // See https://sendgrid.com/docs/User_Guide/Settings/tracking.html
        msg.SetClickTracking(false, false);

        return client.SendEmailAsync(msg);
    }
}
```

### RegisterConfirmation.cshtml:

```
DisplayConfirmAccountLink = false;
```

Comment: Try putting `client.SendEmailAsync(msg)` in a try catch block and see if there are any exceptions thrown. Also `await` your tasks otherwise the exceptions will be swallowed.

Comment: Are you using the email "info@example.com" to send with? You can only send emails with SendGrid using email addresses that you have verified either as a [single sender](https://docs.sendgrid.com/ui/sending-email/sender-verification) or through [domain authentication](https://docs.sendgrid.com/ui/account-and-settings/how-to-set-up-domain-authentication).